# xcode 4.5 takes more than 2 seconds to switch tab

Tags: xcode4, xcode4.5

I upgraded to XCode 4.5 and when I click on a tab to switch on it it takes more than 2 seconds to switch on it.

Anyone have experienced and solved same issue?

Comment: I have the same issue.It takes Xcode 4 seconds to switch tabs, and the xcode process goes up to 120% CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a common issue. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/167765?tstart=0

Bug report has been submitted so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

**Edit - Seems to be fixed with XCode 4.5.1**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have experienced exactly the same. On my machine it can take like 3-4 seconds to switch tabs in Xcode.

Luckily the issue goes away by restarting xcode. (A lame work-around, I know, but the only one that I have found so far).